# Comparing Arrays and if both match, push into new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am looping through an array called `race` and within it is an array called `time`. I need to compare the contents of the array `time` with the contents of the array `speed`. If both contents exactly match, I need to push `race[i]` into the empty array called `filtered`.  For some reason, when I run this filter, all arrays within `race` are pushed into `filtered`. Any idea why it would be doing this? Here's the code:

```
angular
  .module('raceApp')
  .filter('certFilter', function() {
  return function(race, speed) {
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < race.length; i++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < race[i].data.time.length; k++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < speed.length; j++) {
          if (race[i].data.time[k] === speed[j] && filtered.indexOf(race[i]) == -1) {
            filtered.push(race[i]);
          } else {
            filtered.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    console.log('filtered', filtered);
    return filtered;
  }
});


console.log('filtered', filtered);
return filtered;
}
});
```

Comment: You're not comparing the whole contents, you're just comparing individual elements.

Comment: @Barmar what's the best way to compare the whole contents without looping?

Comment: You have to loop. But not nested loops like you have. You should be looping once, comparing corresponding elements in both arrays. Isn't it explained well in the linked question?